# How to integrate web service (soap) with JUnit

Tags: eclipse, web-services, junit, soapui

I am having few web services and working good with soapUI tool. I am trying to run as a suite. I have soapUI, junit and all other necessary libraries added to eclipse and system path has been setup to : `soapUI.Junit = C://Doc and Sett/mkd/soapUI 4.2/bin/`.

I have written @Before, @Test and @after methods. In @Test I have code something like below:

```
@Test
public void somex() {
    SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner(); 
    runner.setProjectFile( "src/dist/sample-soapui-project.xml" );
    runner.run(); 
}
```

But this code doesn't work. It is not able to recognise `SoapUITestCaseRunner`. Can someone help me with solution, please.?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it is not able to recognise SoapUITestCaseRunner"?  It doesn't compile?  You get a class not found error?  What exception is thrown?

Comment: I can see compiler error in eclipse. If i compile i get "ClassNotFound" Exception.

Comment: Sounds to me like you missed a jar file for the SoapUI test classes.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `soapui-a.b.c.jar(e.g. soapui-2.0.2.jar)` to the classpath.then problem will be solved.